# Vue 3 + Tailwind dynamic components + arbitrary values

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

Working on my Vue 3 portfolio, I found a very weird bug.

When I have my App.vue and I call my custom component, the css is not shown in the inspector ie. the code doesn't work.

It does render the classes to the DOM (ie. w-[20px], h-[30px] etc), but I don't see any styling in the CSS window for it. The other css of Tailwind is shown (ie. z-index (z-10).

So I think I can't use arbitrary values in my child components.

Why doesn't it apply the styles of the arbitrary values? Is it too quick?

Here is my Child Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex absolute" :class="'left-[' + left + '] top-[' + top + '] z-' + zIndex + ' 3xl:top-[' + tripleXLTop + ']'">
        <img :src="image" alt="" :class="'w-[' + width + 'px] h-[' + height + 'px] ' + animation" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    isDesktop: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    left: {
        type: String
    },
    top: {
        type: String
    },
    tripleXLTop: {
        type: String
    },
    zIndex: {
        type: String
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    },
    width: {
        type: String
    },
    height: {
        type: String
    },
    animation: {
        type: String
    }
})
</script>
```

And here is how I call it in App.vue:

```
 <BackgroundImage :image="'../src/assets/img/plant-berry.svg'" :left="'15%'" :top="'-9%'" :triple-x-l-top="'100px'" :z-index="'10'" :width="'250'" :height="'194'" :animation="'animate-swaying7'" />
```

This is the result I see in the DOM.
As you can see, it renders the arbitrary values, but not the corresponding css:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already found it. You need to send the entire string instead of just the value. Too bad but it works:

```
    <BackgroundImage :image="'../src/assets/img/plant-berry.svg'"  :z-index="'10'" :width="'w-[250px]'" :height="'h-[194px]'" :animation="'animate-swaying7'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> Don't construct class names dynamically
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```

You could consider passing the class names directly, like:

```js
<BackgroundImage
  image="../src/assets/img/plant-berry.svg"
  class="left-[15%] top-[-9%] 3xl:top-[100px] z-10"
  imageClasses="w-[250px] h-[194px]"
  animation="animate-swaying7"
/>
```

```js
<template>
    <div class="flex absolute">
        <img :src="image" alt="" :class="[imageClasses, animation]" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    isDesktop: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    },
    imageClasses: {
        type: String
    },
    animation: {
        type: String
    }
})
</script>
```

Or you could use the `style` attribute:

```js
<BackgroundImage
  image="../src/assets/img/plant-berry.svg"
  left="15%"
  top="-9%"
  triple-x-l-top="100px"
  z-index="10"
  width="250"
  height="194"
  animation="animate-swaying7"
/>
```

```js
<template>
    <div
      class="flex absolute 3xl:top-[--3xl-top]"
      :style="{
        top,
        left,
        zIndex,
        '--3xl-top': tripleXLTop,
      }">
        <img
          :src="image"
          alt=""
          :class="animation"
          :style="{
            width: `${width}px`,
            height: `${height}px`,
          }"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    isDesktop: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    left: {
        type: String
    },
    top: {
        type: String
    },
    tripleXLTop: {
        type: String
    },
    zIndex: {
        type: String
    },
    image: {
        type: String
    },
    width: {
        type: String
    },
    height: {
        type: String
    },
    animation: {
        type: String
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, after building and deploying to Netlify, all the images are not there, even though the paths are correct. The images that are static in App.vue do show up in the Netlify deploy...

Comment: You'd probably want to fix that, and then either of the above solutions should work.